# Embedding simple block diagrams in GitHub wiki

Tags: github, images, github-wiki

I'd like to add some simple block diagrams to my GitHub wiki. Is there any way to do this without embedding images?

Comment: How else have other places added block diagrams?

Comment: I suppose I meant some form of textual markup rather than binary files. Since [Gollum](https://github.com/github/gollum) supports sequence diagrams, and since simple block diagrams are such a valuable tool in software documentation, I wondered if there was an easy way to create them within GitHub wikis.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [umlet-github](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/umlet-github/paimimbkklhmfcbbgmhpfpjaikijhppl), a Google Chrome extension that allows you to create diagrams in [UMLet](http://www.umlet.com/), store them as UXF files in your repository and view them in your browser within the GitHub interface.

[image: umlet-github converts UXF into SVG]

At the moment umlet-github does not support GitHub wiki's however I'm working on a project to solve some of the larger problems in this area at the moment and will update this answer to reflect developments.

Answer (score 1):

You might try Figurepool to create a diagram, generate a Markdown code snippet that it provides and just copy paste the snippet into the Github wiki. Check out this blog post: http://figurepool.com/blog/Embedding_images_and_diagrams_in_github_wiki_pages_and_issue_tracker.html.